# How to recover history commands?

Tags: unix

I have ran certain commands in korn shell script as follows:

```
324 pwd
325 list 
326 cd mpiomp 
327 list 
328 cd C 
329 list 
330 history
```

How can I retrieve the `pwd` command by using `r` ?
Currently I am using `r -324` but its not working.

Comment: Please define "Not working". What do you expect to see and what do you see instead?

Comment: I want to recover "324 pwd" command . what command i should use to get it?

Comment: I understand what you want, but you said "I am using `r -324` but it's not working". What happens instead when you type `r -324`? You have to be more specific about what you see.

Comment: it's showing error . "unmatched range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/r.1.asp) of the `r` commands shows that you are using it wrong. here are the relevant parts:

> The r command (a built-in KornShell alias) re-executes a command you ran previously, possibly editing it first. Commands are obtained from your command history file.
>
> The specifier tells which command you want to re-execute. It can have
>   any of the following forms:
>
> An unsigned number (*n*)
>   Run the command with that number.
>
> A negative number (*-n*)
>   Runs the command that came n commands before the current one.

As you can see, calling the command `r 324` will execute the command with that history number.